# Is it possible to change two styles independently inside the same link tag on a:hover?

Tags: css, hover

I have an anchor link which has an image and two spans of text, a title and a tagline with different colors, and i want them to change differently when hovering the link.

```
<style>
span.title {color: #666;}
span.tagline {color: #aaa;}
</style>

<a class="button" href="http://www.link.com" target="_blank">
<div style="display:block">
<img src="images/button.png">
<span class="title">TITLE</span><br>
<span class="tagline">tagline</span>
</div>
</a>
```

I wonder if it's possible to use something like:

```
<style>
a.button:hover span.title {color: #000;}
a.button:hover span.tagline {color: #2ae;}
</style>
```

Comment: yes it's possible.Have you tried it? http://jsfiddle.net/7exKT/

Comment: You've already answered your own question http://jsfiddle.net/4zSRC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes thats possible. Psuedo class `:hover` doesn't have to be for the last element in the selector.

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/H35rf/*

For future reference its easier/quicker to try this out for yourself in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) before asking questions.